# ActiveXObject is not defined

Tags: enterprise-architect

Getting error "ActiveXObject is not defined" executing this script:

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript
function main()
{
     var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
}
main();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the required libraries installed.
I tried your code in my EA (v11.1) and it worked without issues.
A search for the error revealed that it might have something to do with Internet Explorer, see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx